# How can you split HDMI 1.4b control signals to two displays?

Tags: hdmi

I have been tasked to implement an HDMI splitter on a PCB along with other interface connections. The intent would be to utilize one built in display and have the option of a second plug-in display with the same visual. I have identified [PI3HDX412BDZBEX](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/PI3HDX412BDZBEX?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduh6PnBBOT2gcPSviPlx2UpArlAfN0gisfAxIXySd5zyQREnJm9CzqZO&utm_source=octopart&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=729-PI3HDX412BDZBEX&utm_content=Diodes%20Incorporated) as a possible solution, but it only manages the TMDS signals, not the control lines for CEC, HPD and DDC.

I think HPD and CEC can be merged easily, but how can or should DDC be split to two displays?

Answer (score 2):

No, DDC cannot be split into two displays. You should at least multiplex a bus so each display can be talked to separately. But your original source must be aware of this, usually splitting of DDC is not supported.

If the TMDS is splitted, there can be no support for HDCP protection as that is for single point-to-point link only.

And HPD neither, they are both outputs from TV, they both must control their own output, regarding TMDS, DDC and CEC.

And also, connecting CEC to two displays is invalid, there cannot be two CEC masters on the bus.

You must use a special splitter chip, that has three ports, one for input, two for output, and which allows a MCU to manage DDC and HPD, perhaps HDCP too.